# Google Maps Polyline: calculate endpoint from original point

Tags: navigation, google-maps-api-3

I want to draw a polyline using Google Maps.
I have read the API and did some research, but i am still left with a fundamental question.

Information:

```
lat: 63.43243500
lon: 10.37045667
angle: 230 degrees (0 = north)
```

How can i make a polyline that is 60 meters long that originates from the original lat / lon with a angle of 230 degrees?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to calculate the endpoint of the line in (lat,lon).  This can be done using the `calculateOffset` function in the [google.maps.geometry.spherical namespace](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#spherical).  It has three required parameters: the starting lat/lng point, the distance to travel, and the heading angle.

Here's an example for your situation:

```js
var startLL = new google.maps.LatLng(63.43243500,10.37045667);
var endLL = new google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(startLL, 60, 230);
```

From [the Polyline example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Polylines), you can create a Polyline from these points as:

```js
var coordinates = [startLL, endLL];
var path = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path: coordinates,
  strokeColor: "#FF0000",
  strokeOpacity: 1.0,
  strokeWeight: 2
});
```

---

**Update:** You also need to make sure that you include the `geometry` library, which is not included by default.  Following the instructions [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#Libraries), you need to change your bootstrap request to:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false
```

Comment: @HyperDevil - Okay, I figured this out.  It was a little tricky since I've never used javascript or the Google Maps API.  You need to make sure you add the `geometry` library.  See my edit above.  [Here's a corrected fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3CvaD/85/)